# JQuery plugins in Angular or Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins

I frequently heard and read that we are not supposed to use [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) with [Angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts). But what if I want to use some [JQuery plugins](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) that are not available in Angularjs.
For now, I don't have any idea about the examples but what if I face the situation? How to proceed with jquery plugins? What might be the best approaches?

**UPDATE**

For example, [JQuery slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) has more functionalities than [Angular Carousel](https://mihnsen.github.io/ui-carousel/), a case something like this, not everyone wants to develop their own and often wants to use the plugin that has more functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

So far we are using Angular2 + jQuery in production for 9 months. It really don't make problems at all. Our case - Kendo for jQuery. It has lots of good controls and we are happy to use them. Kendo for Angular2 right now don't provide most of Kendo for jQuery. You may see sample code below.

```
     private initialize() {
        let instance = this;

        const data = instance.events.map((event) => {
            return {
                end: new Date(Date.parse(event.to)),
                id: event.id,
                start: new Date(Date.parse(event.from)),
                title: event.name,
                description: event.name
            };
        });

        const dataSource = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({ data });

        const schedulerDate = new Date(instance.date.getTime());
        schedulerDate.setHours(0);
        schedulerDate.setMinutes(0);
        schedulerDate.setSeconds(0);

        const startDate = new Date(schedulerDate.getTime());
        startDate.setHours(this.applicationSettings.workStartTimeMinutes / 60);
        const finishDate = new Date(schedulerDate.getTime());
        finishDate.setHours(this.applicationSettings.workEndTimeMinutes / 60);

        const finalOptions: kendo.ui.SchedulerOptions = {
            dataSource: data,
            date: schedulerDate,
            views: ['day'],
            startTime: startDate,
            endTime: finishDate,
            footer: false,
            editable: false,
            majorTimeHeaderTemplate: kendo.template('#=kendo.toString(date, "HH:mm")#'),
        };

        const jqElement = $(instance._schedulerContainer.element.nativeElement);
        let existingGrid = <kendo.ui.Scheduler>jqElement.data('kendoScheduler');
        if (existingGrid) {
            existingGrid.destroy();
        }

        instance._kendoScheduler = <kendo.ui.Scheduler>jqElement.kendoScheduler(finalOptions).data('kendoScheduler');

        instance._kendoScheduler.wrapper.on('mousedown', 'div.k-event', function (e) {
            const uid = $(e.currentTarget).data('uid');
            const event = instance._kendoScheduler.occurrenceByUid(uid);
            instance._augmentedReality.openTask2(event.id);
        });
    }
```

As you can see, nothing special. If you use typescript then `@types/kendo-ui` package for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I would reword that statement about not using jQuery with AngularJS - it's not that you are "not supposed to use jQuery with AngularJS". It's that if you want to leverage the power of the framework, you need to think about your problem in terms of your view just being a visual display of a data model, and that you manipulate that data model as you need to and let the framework update the view as needed.

This is in contrast to jQuery where, for the most part, you have to think about your problem in terms of manipulating the user interface for it to do what you want.

Because of the different mental approaches, it's usually a good idea to stop reaching for jQuery to solve your problems until you have a good grasp of the AngularJS method of solving problems. But, once you have that mental model, AngularJS has hooks to leverage jQuery plugins as you need. But before building that mental model, using jQuery to solve problems will prevent you from learning how to leverage the framework properly.

For a lot of people, after you learn how to think about your problem with that different mindset, you realise how little you actually need jQuery, unless you're trying to use an existing plugin. (And you also notice how you can quickly build your own AngularJS versions of many simple jQuery plugins, as well).